# Rails & SimpleMDE - content displays indented

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, markdown, wysiwyg, simplemde

I've installed [SimpleMDE](https://github.com/NextStepWebs/simplemde-markdown-editor) on my rails app on a textarea for creating posts. The issue I have is when I want to edit the content of the post.body (ie the textarea that has the simplemde) looks indented like you see on the screenshot:

[image]

I have viewed the source code on show action in case it generates some extra tags, but the markdown looks fine

[image]

which makes me think that its something wrong with the editor. How can I fix this indentation that shows on the editor?

Here is also my code

```
# The gemfile
gem 'simplemde', '~> 0.1.0'
gem 'redcarpet', '~> 3.4'
# gem 'html-pipeline', '~> 2.5'
# gem 'github-markdown', '~> 0.6.9'
# gem 'sanitize', '~> 4.4'

# the _form.html.haml file
= f.input :body, as: :text, input_html: { class: 'simplemde' }

# the coffescript file
simplemde = null
$(document).on 'turbolinks:before-visit', ->
  if simplemde?
    simplemde.toTextArea()
    simplemde = null

$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  simplemde = new SimpleMDE(element: $('.simplemde')[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution, so I'm going to post it here just in case anyone else needs it.

https://github.com/NextStepWebs/simplemde-markdown-editor/issues/480

Basically all needed todo was to replace

```
= f.input :body
```

with

```
~ f.input :body # notice the tilde symbol
```

and this would fix everything.

However if there's a much better solution, I'd appreciate if someone would post it.